# Полноэкранный режим для html5 по dblclick

Tags: javascript, html5

На `HTML5-видеоплеер` необходимо повесить по `ondblclick` вход в полноэкранный режим и выход из него. И если, например, относительно `play/pause` существует `targetElement.paused`, то не существует `targetElement.fullScreenInActive`.

Поэтому не вижу средств проверить в полном экране плеер или нет. А без этого, как мне кажется, реализация невозможна.

По сути, надо чередовать эти функции в зависимости от того, в полноэкранном режиме плеер или нет:

```
function fullScreen() {
if (player.requestFullscreen) {
player.requestFullscreen();
} else if (player.msRequestFullscreen) {
player.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (player.mozRequestFullScreen) {
player.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
player.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
}

function exitFullScreen() {
if (document.exitFullscreen) {
document.exitFullscreen();
} else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
document.webkitExitFullscreen();
} else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
document.mozCancelFullScreen();
} else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
document.msExitFullscreen();
}
}
```

Похожий вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768320/html5-video-double-click-to-go-full-screen), но я, к сожалению, не смог разобраться без примеров.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode#Toggling_fullscreen_mode

можно еще проверить, если FS не получился, просто растянуть элемент на все окно

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашёл. Сделал функцию так:

```
    function isFullscreen() {
 if (document.fullscreenElement
  || document.webkitFullscreenElement
  || document.mozFullScreenElement
  || document.msFullscreenElement) {
    return true;
    }
    }
```